# get monit to restart on failure but alert on cycle

Tags: monit

I'd like to do something like this in monit:

```
check process foo with pidfile /var/run/foo/foo.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/foo start" with timeout 30 seconds
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/foo stop"

  if does not exist then restart
  if does not exist for 3 cycles then alert
```

But monit seems to overwrite the first "if does not exist" check with the second, so I lose my process restarting and only get alerting.

I realize that I could just not bother with cycles and have it restart and alert, but that can be fairly noisy when dealing with a large number of servers.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to say "if does not exist then restart"

Assuming the process is monitored, monit will automatically restart it when it detects it's not there.

Comment: Yes, it's implicit normally, but the `then alert` line seems to override that default restart behavior.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but this might be worth a try. Remove "if does not exist then restart" and instead of saying "if does not exist for 3 cycles then alert," say "if 3 restarts within 3 cycles then alert"